# Filter Created in SP REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, filter

I have this code below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
           url: res3 + "/_api/web/lists('" + normlistid + "')/items('" + normid +"')?$select=ID,Title,Created,QuemLeu/Id&$expand=QuemLeu",
           method: "GET",
           headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
                     },
           success: function (data) {
                    if(data.d){
                            if(data.d.QuemLeu.results){
                                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.QuemLeu.results.length; i++){
                                    if(data.d.QuemLeu.results[i].Id == userId){
                                            document.getElementById(itemHTML).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                            console.log("User Found.");
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    console.log("User Not Found");
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
```

How can I filter if the created field (Sharepoint column) is greater than "2018/10/05"?

Comment: I don't understand you question but if you want to check if Created column is grater then '2018/10/05' (year/month/day?) use`new Date(data.d.Created) > new Date("2018-10-05")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SharePoint REST API endpoints take **ISO formatted date** string for filtering.

Try using below query for filtering on Date Field:

1. To check greater than `2018/10/05`:

```
https://[tentat]/sites/[site]/Normativo/ComunicacoesDeNegocio/_api/web/lists('e97f928b-34e4-34e2-c2c7-150ea469fac3')/items?$select=ID,Title,Created,QuemLeu/Id&$expand=QuemLeu&$filter=(Created gt datetime'2018-10-05T00:00:00Z')
```

2. To check greater than or equal to `2018/10/05`:

```
https://[tentat]/sites/[site]/Normativo/ComunicacoesDeNegocio/_api/web/lists('e97f928b-34e4-34e2-c2c7-150ea469fac3')/items?$select=ID,Title,Created,QuemLeu/Id&$expand=QuemLeu&$filter=(Created ge datetime'2018-10-05T00:00:00Z')
```

**Answer For Updated Question**:

Add one more `IF` statement inside `if(data.d)` like given below:

```
if(data.d){
    if(new Date(data.d.Created) > new Date("2018-10-05")) {
        console.log("Items is created after '2018-10-05'");
    } else {
        console.log("Items is created before '2018-10-05'");
        //Add your other code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this works for you?

Comment: The thing is I need `/items('193')/` to my code working. There is another way?

Comment: Actually `/items('193')/` gives you the single item from list. So you cannot apply filter on such endpoint. Can you tell us what is the exact requirement of yours??

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: What is the significance of `datetime` in the filter query when it is used like this: 
 `datetime'2018-10-05T00:00:00Z'` - is `datetime` a method?  I've googled for it but can't find docs on it.  What does `datetime` do?  Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Add `$filter` to your query and use `Created gt datetime'2018-10-05T00:00:00'` or `Created gt '2018-10-05'`

```
/_api/web/lists('guid')/items?$select=ID,Title,Created,QuemLeu/Id&$expand=QuemLeu&$filter=Created gt '2018-10-05'
```

Comment: Hello, your expression is not valid.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I blindly copied your URL. The issue was with `/items('193')/` it has to be only `/items/`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I did fixed it first and get down vote, awesome :D

Comment: The thing is I need `/items('193')/` to my code working. There is another way?

Comment: So what do you want to filter? Using `/items(193)/` will give you only one item, so there is nothing to filter. Update your question please, because apparently you want something different.

Comment: I updated my post and I didn't vote -1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
&$filter=Created gt '2018-10-05'
```

At the end of your endpoint

For example:

```
https://[tentat]/sites/[site]/Normativo/ComunicacoesDeNegocio/_api/web/lists('e97f928b-34e4-34e2-c2c7-150ea469fac3')/items('193')?$select=ID,Title,Created,QuemLeu/Id&$expand=QuemLeu&$filter=Created gt '2018-10-05'
```

Gt operator means **"greater than"**

And also you can check all operators below:

```
Lt (less than)

Le (less than or equal)

Gt (greater than)

Ge (greater than or equal)

Eq (equal to)

Ne (not equal to)
```

Comment: Hello, your filter is not working, is giving me the error "the query is not valid."

Answer (score 1):

Use filter property `$filter=Created gt '2018-10-17'`

Comment: Hello, your expression seems to be not valid.

Comment: Now, is giving me "the query is not valid".

Comment: You use this filter  under Items:  /_api/web/lists('guid')/items?$filter=Created gt '2018-10-17'

Comment: The thing is I need `/items('193')/` to my code working. There is another way?

Comment: Why i get -1 if you dont understand how its working? Filter you can use only about collection of items.... If you need to get 193 item, you will get it, but you have only 1 item and there is nothing to filter, you should do after this IF statement not the Filter

Comment: I updated my post, I didn't vote -1

Comment: So you updated your post and now as I wroted, you need IF statement, cause you only need to check if Created is GT DATE. Thats everything.