# Power Automate Reminder flow error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, flow, power-automate

I am trying to create a flow that takes the Expiry date from the list and sends an email to outlook.
This is my list:

[image]

This is my flow:

[image]

I have added this string (Should send a reminder when 1 day is left for the expiry date):

```
FormatDateTime(addDays(utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd'), +1)
```

When I run my flow I always get an error:

[image]

Could you help me identify why is there this error informing that:

> "The expression "expire date eq '2021-11-18'" is not valid. Creating query failed.
> clientRequestId: c45f4aad-2999-4ece-a4f5-d56490163c7a
> serviceRequestId: c45f4aad-2999-4ece-a4f5-d56490163c7a"

Comment: Does my below response answered your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct **internal name** (not display name) of your expiry date column in Filter Query.

Check below URL to find out the internal name of SharePoint column:

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

---

Also, check how to filter on date columns using correct filter query format. Follow below link for more information:

1. [Filter Created in SP REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555)