# Filter Query with Rest API (Internal Name or New Name)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, filter

I am making a fetch to retrieve information from a SharePoint list that meet a certain criteria.

I need the EndDate to be greater than or equal to todays date. I also need to other columns to equal a certain value. HRStatus and SupervisorStatus need to both equal 'Approved'.

Here is the setup for the request:

```
const compareDate = new Date();

const formatCompareDate = moment(compareDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

const empArray = [Array of Names I want to pull];

var filters = empArray.map(function(emp){
    return "EmployeeName/Title eq '" + emp + "'";
});


const leaveRequest = new Request(
    "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Leave Request')/items?$select=EmployeeName/Title,ID,StartDate,EndDate,LeavePurpose,Title,HRStatus,SupervisorStatus&$expand=EmployeeName&$filter=EndDate ge '" + formatCompareDate + "'and HRStatus eq 'Approved' and SupervisorStatus eq 'Approved' and " + filters.join(' or ')
    , {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',        
        headers: new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        })
    }
);
```

This is returning all items with the correct cormatCompareDate but it is pulling items that have a null response for either Status Field. I need both of them to be the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using endpoint like this:

```
"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Leave Request')/items?$select=EmployeeName/Title,ID,StartDate,EndDate,LeavePurpose,Title,HRStatus,SupervisorStatus&$expand=EmployeeName&$filter=EndDate ge '" + formatCompareDate + "'and HRStatus eq 'Approved' and SupervisorStatus eq 'Approved' and (" + filters.join(' or ') + ")"
```

And you have to use the "internal names" of columns in REST endpoint everywhere (in `$select`, `$expand` as well as in `$filter`).

You can get the internal names of your columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

---

**Additional Information**:

For date column filtering, refer: [Filter Created in SP REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555)