# SharePoint rest api Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm looking for a way to retrieve all files modified after a given time on SharePoint.

I've tried accessing the endpoints `_api/web/lists/getbytitle` (Query 1), which only seems to return folders and `_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` (Query 2), which only returns files in a given folder.

Is there a way to search all files changed after a certain date in a document library?

This is the documentation I'm using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Query 1:

```
https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/036222/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project%20Files')/items?$filter= Modified gt '2022-09-30T12:56:11'
```

Query 2:

```
https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/036222/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Project%20Files')/files?$filter= Modified gt '2022-09-30T12:56:11'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this SharePoint REST API endpoint:

```
https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/036222/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project Files')/items?$filter=Modified gt datetime'2022-09-30T12:56:11.000Z'
```

Comment: Did that, but it only returns changed folders.

https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/036222/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project%20Files')/items?$filter=Modified gt datetime'2022-10-04T09:00:00.000Z'

That retrieves modified files and I missed the datetime in the formula.....

Why do w add the .000Z
Isn't 2022-10-04T09:00:00 already in that date time format?

Comment: Is it working for you as expected or not?

Comment: You can ignore `.000Z` part (milliseconds) as well if not required. Check different ways to filter based on date column in SharePoint REST API at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555

Comment: Yes working as expected now! thanks.

Where do I click that you solved this? i can't find it

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!