# Get Items is not getting the latest items

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

I have a SharePoint list with around 100,000 items, and I have 5600++ items with a field named ExpiryDate = 7 June 2023

[image]

but when I defined the following Get_Items inside a manual flow (which get called from a scheduled flow) with this filter query, I only get one item out of 5600++ items!!.. any advice?

```
ExpiryDate eq '2023-04-22' or ExpiryDate eq '2023-05-08' or ExpiryDate eq '2023-06-07'
```

[image]

Any advice what is going on ? Now I have added an index to the ExpiryDate when I first created the list..

Here is the Get_Items settings

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of ExpiryDate column? Is it a string column or Date and Time column?

Comment: @Harsh it is a Date Only (without time) column type. thanks

Comment: Try adding `datetime` just after the `eq` and let me know if that works.

Comment: @Harsh what i need to do exactly ? can you post the formula?

Comment: Try with this formula : `ExpiryDate eq datetime '<your variable>'`. If eq doesn't give you the expected result, then you can try with other other operators like `ge` or `le`.

Comment: Hi @microsoftdeveloperdesigner, Does below answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try generating and using SharePoint REST API endpoint in Get Items action in Power automate flow like this:

```
https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=(ExpiryDate ge datetime'2023-04-22T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-04-22T23:59:000Z') or (ExpiryDate ge datetime'2023-05-08T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-05-08T23:59:000Z') or (ExpiryDate ge datetime'2023-06-07T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-06-07T23:59:000Z')
```

**Similar thread**: [Power Automate Filter query on created date column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305192/power-automate-filter-query-on-created-date-column/305193#305193)