# Rest API GetItems is not returning all the records

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow

I have tried this REST API and I got one item correctly:

```
https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=ExpiryDate eq '2023-04-25' or ExpiryDate eq '2023-05-11' or ExpiryDate eq '2023-06-10'
```

[image]

But if I type this date I will only get one item although I have more than 300 items which should match this criteria:

```
https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=ExpiryDate eq '2023-04-25' or ExpiryDate eq '2023-05-11' or ExpiryDate eq '2023-06-07'
```

[image]

So what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be that the date filter uses ISOSTRING format.

So "ExpiryDate eq datetime'2023-05-11T00:00:00.000Z'" instead of "ExpiryDate eq '2023-05-11'"

Example: [REST API filter by start and end dates using 'today'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105576/rest-api-filter-by-start-and-end-dates-using-today)

Comment: so how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use PNP-js Library to get all Items in SPFx**

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("BigList").items.filter("YourFilter").getAll()
```

**Or You can Try your API Like this**

```
https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=(ExpiryDate eq '2023-04-25T00:00:00.000Z') or (ExpiryDate eq '2023-05-11T00:00:00.000Z')
```

Comment: but i am using Power automate not pnp

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: thanks for the reply but how i can format my Date field as `2023-04-25T00:00:00.000Z` .. also the expirtDate in my case is of type DateOnly (without time)

Comment: You can just append the string "T00:00:00.000Z" in your date format

Answer (score 0):

Try using SharePoint REST API endpoint like this:

```
https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=(ExpiryDate ge datetime'2023-04-25T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-04-25T23:59:00Z') or (ExpiryDate ge datetime'2023-05-11T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-05-11T23:59:00Z') or (ExpiryDate ge datetime'2023-06-07T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-06-07T23:59:00Z')
```

**Similar thread**: [Power Automate Filter query on created date column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305192/power-automate-filter-query-on-created-date-column/305193#305193)

Comment: your call will raise this error "value: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.""

Comment: Check updated answer. changed `000Z` to `00Z` and tested. It is working for me. Are you including `datetime` keyword in your filter query as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Is this working for you now?