# Filtering SP List using created

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience

I want to filter the SP list using created date so that list items created in last 8 days get displayed.

I am using:

```
private getCarouselListContent = () => {   
  try {
     let requestUrl = `${this.props.absoluteURL}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('${this.props.listName}')/Items?$select=*$filter=Created eq '[Today]-8'`;
      this.props.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
     .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse)=>{
       if(response.ok){

        response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
          // Log the response to the console
          console.log(responseJSON);

          this.setState(({  
            value: responseJSON.value            
          })); 
          return responseJSON;
        });
         
       } 
     }).then((item: any) => {      
       if (item!=null){ 
       try{            
             this.setState(({  
               value: item.value             
             })); 
                        
           }
           catch(err){      
            
           }
         }
       });
      } catch (error) {    
     console.log('error in service ', error);  
   }
 }
```

Can you help me with correct endpoint?

Comment: You cannot use [Today] in SharePoint REST API. You have to use the date filters as shown here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `[Today]` in SharePoint REST API requests. Try using below:

```
let dCurrentDate = new Date();
let dStartDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-8));
let sCurrentDate = dCurrentDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (dCurrentDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dCurrentDate.getDate() + "T00:00:00.000Z";
let sStartDate = dStartDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (dStartDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dStartDate.getDate() + "T00:00:00.000Z";

let requestUrl = `${this.props.absoluteURL}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('${this.props.listName}')/items?$select=*&$filter=Created ge datetime'${sStartDate}' and Created le datetime'${sCurrentDate}'`;
```

**Reference**: [Filter Created in SP REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555)