# I want to retrieve SharePoint report using API & JSON. For example for getting the number of Applications between a set time period from list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem

I need to generate or retrieve report from a SharePoint list using API endpoint. I believe we can request it in JSON by setting the Request headers to "Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose".

Kindly help with the code.

For example for getting the number of Applications submitted successfully or not between a set time period.

```
{SchemeSiteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Applications')/items?$select=SubmissionId&$top=100000&$filter=(Created%20gt%20datetime%272023-10-01T01:00:00%27)%20and%20(Created%20lt%20datetime%272023-10-26T01:00:00%27)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch the SharePoint list items using the SharePoint REST API, you can use the code like below.

**Example** - JavaScript/JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="getSPListItems()"> Get SharePoint List Items</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSPListItems() {
        var itemsEndpoint = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Applications')/items?$select=Title,SubmissionId&$top=5000&$filter=(Created gt datetime'2023-10-01T01:00:00') and (Created lt datetime'2023-10-26T01:00:00')";

        $.ajax({
            url: itemsEndpoint,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d.results);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Documentations**:

1. [Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)
2. [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

**Related read**:

1. [Filter SharePoint list items based on Created column using SharePoint REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555)