How to fix this filter issue in share point flow for archiving the old data's
I am receiving below error in power automate flow:

"The expression "Created It '2023-09-25T08:51:03.3064394Z'" is not valid. Creating query failed.\r\nclientRequestId: 3adee6af-6e39-463f-a1e8-ed55a98a0f33\r\nserviceRequestId: 6f5653a1-1028-6000-82b5-943418742b8b"

Could you please help me to rectify this issue?

Can you share screenshot of your flow? which flow action are you using? How are you generating filter query?

Is this a date & time (included) column in SharePoint? For testing --> try query like this once and see if it works: Created lt '2023-09-25' OR Created lt datetime'2023-09-25T08:51:03Z'. Let me know either of these works. Reference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555

I think you are using wrong operator in your filter query. It should be "less than" (lt) and not It.
Try using below queries and see which one works for you (I prefer #1 from below list):
Created lt datetime'2023-09-25T08:51:03Z'

OR
Created lt '2023-09-25T08:51:03Z'

OR
Created lt '2023-09-25'

Reference: Filter Created in SP REST API
